# Order DataTable rows with Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, datatable

I'm trying to pass an `ArrayList` into a `DataRow` object, the idea being to import data into a database from a CSV.

Previously in the file, a `Dictionary<string,int>` has been created, with the column name as the Key, and the position index as the corresponding value.

I was planning on using this to create a temporary `DataTable` for each record to aid importing into the DB. My original idea was something along the lines of:

```
private DataRow ArrayListToDataRow(ArrayList data, Dictionary<string,int> columnPositions)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataColumn dc = new DataColumn();
    for (i=0;i<=data.Count;i++)
    {
        dc.ColumnName = columnPositions.Keys[i];
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);
        dt.Columns[columnPositions.Keys[i]].SetOrdinal(columnPositions(columnPositions.Keys[i]);
    }
//TODO Add data to row
}
```

But of course, the keys aren't indexable.

Does anybody have an idea on how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the size of data should be the same as the size of your columnPositions, you could try using a foreach over your dictionary instead of a for loop.

If you want to access your dictionary values based on a sortable index, you would need to change it to

```
Dictionary<int, string>
```

Which seems to make more sense, as you seem to want to read them in that order.

If you cannot change the dictionary, you can do something like this

```
var orderedPositions = columnPositions.OrderBy(x => x.Value);
foreach(var position in orderedPositions)
{
  // do your stuff using position.Key and position.Value 
}
```

.OrderBy comes from Linq, so yuo will need to add

```
using System.Linq;
```

to your class.

By ordering the columnPositions on their value (the columnIndex) instead of the default (the order in which items were added), you can loop trough them in the order you presumably want (seeing as you were going with a for loop and every time trying to get the next columnPosition).

Comment: This what I expected would be the case. Unfortunately, there are other routines written by other developers long before myself, that require the Dictionary to be string,int and it would be more work than it's worth to play around with 20+ routines.

Comment: Would you be able to clarify what you are doing here? It would appear that the Dictionary object doesn't contain the OrderBy method. Where is this coming from?

Comment: It's Linq :) Try adding a reference "using System.Linq;"
I added some context, feel free to ask for more clarification if needed :)

Comment: Doh! It's been a long day, my poor old head isn't keeping up. :)

Comment: np :) I know the feeling. Just tested, dictionary does not sort on key by default. That doesn't matter for your case anyway :)